Is this question appropriate for Super User?
Would asking the following question be on topic?

Where are the DB, and DBx stored on the computer whether in the BIOS UEFI, or Operating System?

Or would that best be in the Information Security Stack Exchange?
The DB and DBx are the Authorized Database and Forbidden Database Signature that store EFI signatures to allow, and prevent a computer from booting up.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5016061-secure-boot-db-and-dbx-variable-update-events-37e47cf8-608b-4a87-8175-bdead630eb69

Please do not ask this on Information Security SE. We get too many off-topic questions as it is about non-security, technical issues about security protocols/programs/software etc. Just because a question is about a security protocol/program/software does not mean it is a security question.


Would asking the following question be on topic?

Where are the DB, and DBx stored on the computer whether in the BIOS UEFI, or Operating System?


Yes, it would.

Or would that best be in the Information Security Stack Exchange?

No, it wouldn’t.
Your question is about the nuts and bolts of a security system that are more tied to operational system status and not the overall philosophy of why a security choice was made.
Asking “Where are the DB, and DBx stored on the computer whether in the BIOS UEFI, or Operating System?” is an OS and/or system question.
